# Curl and run script from crontab

Tags: bash, ubuntu, curl, scripting, gitlab

I want to make a cronjob which would get script via curl from gitlab with access token and run it. Everything works when I run it manually but from cron it seems to start and immediately closes root session.

Here's my cronjob

```
35 11 * * * /usr/bin/curl --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: *********' https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/2/repository/files/monitor%2Esh/raw?ref=main | bash -
```

Here's my syslog

```
Aug 07 11:35:01 CRON[1302479]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/curl --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: *********' https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/2/repository/files/monitor)
Aug 07 11:35:01 CRON[1302478]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Header of my script

```
#!/bin/bash
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin/
```

I don't get why curl command is truncated in syslog, is it normal behavior? What am I missing? Or its technically impossible to run script via curl like this?

I've tried to send output to log file by appending

```
>> /var/log/cron_log.log 2>&1
```

but nothing is written there when cron starts job.

Comment: The crontab lines are executed by `sh`, and your command contains in the URL the character `? ` which is a wildcard for sh. Also, you have a %, which is specific to cron. In general, I suggest not to use complex commands in the crontab. Write instead a shell script and call the script from cron; this way, it is also easier to debug.

Comment: Thank you! But I need this script to run directly from gitlab with no files stored on host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percent (%) is a special character in crontab entries which start a new line, try escaping it:

```
35 11 * * * { /usr/bin/curl --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: *********' "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/2/repository/files/monitor\%2Esh/raw?ref=main" | bash -; } >> /var/log/cron_log.log 2>&1
```

Quotes are also added around the URL.

Comment: I've tried double quotes and simple quotes - nothing changes. I've also tried to replace \%2E with . - in syslog filename is full after that but session still closed immediately

Comment: WOW {} did the trick! Everything works like charm! Thank you!!!